# Visualizing "Active Project Value" on Specified Date Range

Tags: looker-studio

I have this this googlesheet

| Start Date | End Date | Project Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/01/01 | 2023/04/30 | 1000 |
| 2023/01/01 | 2023/02/28 | 1000 |
| 2023/02/01 | 2023/03/31 | 1000 |

I am trying to visualizing total active project value per month in googledatastudio/lookerstudio, expected output is like this:

[Expected Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDZ4a.png)

I also want to be able to set the visualization based on minimum date and maximum date, for example if minimum date "2023/02/01" and max date "2023/03/31" it will only show February and March

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*One approach is to `expand` the data within the sheet itself and then on its a straight forward approach to create the expected chart in looker*

***sheets formula***

```js
=reduce({"Date","Value"},sequence(counta(A2:A)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,unique(index(eomonth(sequence(days(index(B2:B,c),index(A2:A,c)-1),1,index(A2:A,c)),))),
         hstack(Σ,wrapcols(index(C2:C,c),counta(Σ),index(C2:C,c)))))))
```

[image]

***Updated formula:***

```js
=reduce({"Project","Date","Value"},sequence(counta(B2:B)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,unique(index(eomonth(sequence(days(index(C2:C,c),index(B2:B,c)-1),1,index(B2:B,c)),))),
         hstack(wrapcols(index(A2:A,c),counta(Σ),index(A2:A,c)),Σ,wrapcols(index(D2:D,c),counta(Σ),index(D2:D,c)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it works! But in case I want to add new column called "Project Name" how can I modify the formula?

Comment: Try the updated formula.